# OpenCV on VS 2013: Cannot open include file: 'tbb/tbb.h': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cmake, tbb

I'm trying to build OpenCV 3.2 with CUDA and TBB enabled.  I've followed the usual directions and generated my solution with CMake.  When I try to build opencv_world in Visual Studio 2013 I get the NVCC error on cuda_compile_generated_median_filter.cu.obj:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tbb/tbb.h': No such file or directory
```

The include path is correct for the TBB package.  I can Ctrl-Shift-G on the include tbb and it navigates to the tbb.h file.  I've restarted the machine. But the compile still fails.

Previously to trying to compile opencv with TBB I successfully compiled opencv without TBB.  The problem is that the TBB include file is not being entered into  cuda_compile_generated_median_filter.cu.obj.depend and isn't in the dependency files upstream.

I'm using Intel's TBB binary so in CMake I have BUILD_TBB unchecked, WITH_TBB checked as well as TBB_ENV* and 
TBB_VER_FILE all set to the correct directories and files.

I've also tried re-configuring and re-generating the Cmake files to no avail.  What do I do now?

Another difficulty I'm running into is that the compiles in VS 2013 are taking a heinous amount of time.  Is there a way to run the CMake from the Windows command prompt which seems to be faster?

Comment: Any solutions/workarounds/anything? Doesn't work in Visual Studio 2017 (with VC14 - Visual Studi0 15 compiler) either.

Comment: So far, it's just crickets.